# Download files from "request" to a specific folder?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am downloading the .txt files using the script below (given the urls in the url.csv). Can you please help me to update the code so that I specify the folder where to save the downloaded .txt files (say "C:\Users\Alberto\Documents\Txt_files")?

```
import csv
import requests
import re

headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0'
}


with open(url.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        fn1 = line[0]
        fn2 = re.sub(r'[/\\]', '', line[1])
        fn3 = re.sub(r'[/\\]', '', line[2])
        fn4 = line[3]
        separat = 'date'
        saveas = '-'.join([fn1, separat, fn4])
        url = 'https://kampanje.mercedes-benz.no/' + line[4].strip()
           
        with open(saveas, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(requests
```

Comment: Could you perhaps give some more details? Does `saveas` contain only the file name you want to save as or a full path?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Saveas contains just the file names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a filename to a base url using Python's `os.path` module, like this:

```py
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join("C:/Users/Alberto/Documents/Txt_files", "hey.txt")
'C:/Users/Alberto/Documents/Txt_files/hey.txt'
```

So your final code would look something like this:

```py
from os import path
import csv
import requests
import re

save_location = "C:/Users/Alberto/Documents/Txt_files"
headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0'
}

with open('url.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        fn1 = line[0]
        fn2 = re.sub(r'[/\\]', '', line[1])
        fn3 = re.sub(r'[/\\]', '', line[2])
        fn4 = line[3]
        separat = 'date'
        saveas = '-'.join([fn1, separat, fn4])
        url = 'https://kampanje.mercedes-benz.no/' + line[4].strip()
        
        # Create a request and update the default user-agent header.
        default_headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
        req_headers = default_headers.update(headers)

        # Send request
        response = requests.get(url, headers=req_headers)

        # Open file and save response content.
        with open(path.join(save_location, saveas), 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
```